# How bad is it to embed UIWebView in UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiwebview

So Apple is saying that UIWebView and UITableView objects shouldn't be embedded in UIScrollView objects. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html

> You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

Does that mean we should never have web or table views inside scroll views? I'm implementing an app that have several web views and table views that scroll with the rest of the content of the view, so scrolling in the web and table views is disabled.

To **never** place web or table views inside scroll views would mean big design changes. Is Apple saying that we should **never** keep web and table views inside scroll views, meaning we can never have them scroll with the rest of the view's content?

Or will it work OK as long as scrolling is disabled for the web and table view embedded in the scroll view? If not - are there any better alternatives other than redesigning the app?

Answer (score 1):

I have used a `UITableView` inside a `UIScrollView` in a production app.

Example:

List of POI's in a `UITableView` and `MKMapView` *next to each other* inside a `UIScrollView` with paging enabled.

The problem was indeed that the scrolling of the `UIScrollView` did not actually work. Especially on the `MKMapView`, as this *scrolls* in all directions. The workaround was to create a custom `UIView` with two `UIButton`'s which act as a custom `UISegmentedControl`. These will actually scroll the `UIScrollView` to the selected *page*.

Some of the things Apple puts in their documentation is probably there to be able to comment on bug reports, or to say: *See, we told you so*.

Comment: Glad to know you've successfully used it in production. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

`UIWebView` ans `UITableView` inherit from a `UIScrollView`, so they will scroll if the content exceed the screen size.
If you use it in a `UIScrollView` its a `UIScrollView` in an other. That's why it can cause problems.

And if you want to use scrolling view in another, you should change the design of your app.

Comment: That depends on how you've set up the bounds or constraints. My question is about the case where scrolling is disabled in the child web and table view. Actually they both inherit from UIView, but I know what you mean.

Comment: If you disabled the scroll in the child, I think it's good. The warning message from Apple is mostly for active scrolling view in an other active scrolling view.

Comment: Thanks. That's my guess as well. Would be cool if it could be somewhat verified. It's a quite scary warning.

Comment: `UIWebView ` does not it inherit from `UIScrollView`. But it has subview of it.